# How can I get the last character of a users input?

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
String sentence = kb.readLine();
int sLength = sentence.length();

if (sentence.charAt(sLength).equals('?')
    System.out.println("Yehey!!!!!");
```

I'm trying to get the last character and compare it to "?", my code doesn't work. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: .chatAt(sLength) will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException... Ranges go from 0 to n - 1. Also, this returns a `char` which is a primitive type: use `==`. `sentence.charAt(sLength - 1) == '?'`

Comment: You need to learn that in programming numbers start with 0, not 1.

Comment: @nikoliazekter Not in all languages.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun ok sorry, i'm not programming languages polyglot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be:

```
sentence.charAt(sLength - 1) == '?'
                        ↑ 
                    Your savior
```

You need -1 because if the String of length `N`, then the last character is at place `N - 1`:

[`String#charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-):

> Returns the char value at the specified index. An index **ranges from 0
>   to `length()` - 1**

Also note that it returns a `char`, and not a `String`. Since `char` is a *primitive*, you cannot invoke `equals`, `==` is just fine.

Comment: "arrays are zero-based" <-- not really; if a `String` is a char array, `.charAt()` is specified by `CharSequence`

Comment: Which is backed up  with array, no?

Comment: ohhh!!!! great!!! i hadnt known about it!!! thank you so much... actually you are my savior... so basically what does -1 mean???

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be. [this project](https://github.com/fge/largetext) implements `CharSequence`, for instance, and is not backed by an array

Comment: @Rae It means minus one, if your string is "hello_world", then "d" is at the 10th place.

Comment: @MarounMaroun , i see because in counting characters it starts with 0???

Comment: @MarounMaroun great!!!! i learn something now!!! thank you so much.... :D have a nice day ahead

Comment: @Rae , You should then accept this answer as it answered your question

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
if (sentence.charAt(sLength-1).equals('?')
        System.out.println("Yehey!!!!!");
```

Because the last **char** of a string is `( array.length() - 1 )`

Comment: NO. `.charAt()` returns a `char`, not a `String`.

Comment: yes i know :)
but String is a an array of char, so the index of its last element is its length - 1

Answer (score -1):

should be:

```
       sentence.charAt(sLength - 1) == '?'
```